# Querying opening curly brace with queries that are using LIKE

Tags: java, sql, oracle, escaping

We have a search functionality in our web application that is working with `Oracle` (version is after `Oracle10g`) and I am building the `SQL` query with `Java`.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/inter.815/a67843/cqspcl.htm#20741), whatever you put in `curly braces {..}` are escaped. However, I would like to provide search for the `{` as well and when I try to search a string that contains `{`, it gives me a `org.hibernate.QueryException: Unmatched braces for alias path` error since it looks for the closing brace.

What I have tried so far;

```
...query... WHERE ... LIKE lower('%{{%') ESCAPE '{'

...query... WHERE ... LIKE lower('%\{%') ESCAPE '\'

...query... WHERE ... LIKE lower('%{{}%')

...query... WHERE ... LIKE lower('%CHR(123)%')

...query... WHERE ... LIKE lower('%||CHR(123)||%')
```

The first two are still causing the error. The other ones are not causing any error, but they don't return results that contains `{`. Is there any work around for this situation?

PS: I can't use prepared statement since the query has legend parts. Unfortunately, it has to be built manually using strings.

PS2: There is no problem with the closing brace `}`

Comment: The ones with `CHR(123)` should look like this: `LIKE '%' || CHR(123) || '%'`. You definitely do not need `LOWER()` here.

Comment: @David, this one worked out really well. Looks a but uglier solution, but I guess I will use this for now. Is there any other work around you know about this situation?

Comment: no, I've never seen or heard of this issue before (but I don't use Hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

LIKE condition was constructed without string concatenation

`...query... WHERE ... LIKE lower('%||CHR(123)||%')` -> `...query... WHERE ... LIKE ('%'||CHR(123)||'%')`

[Env to try this out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8c1e/12)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm):

```
select * from (select 'some string contains {}' as msg from dual
 union select 'some string without curly braces' as msg from dual) t 
where REGEXP_LIKE(t.msg, '.*[{].*')
```

Result: `some string contains {}`

Maybe i wrote incorrect regex for your case, but, at least, you can use it to find any string contains `{`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use `REGEXP_LIKE`. I am limited with the LIKE. There should be a way with the LIKE I suppose. Escaping backslash is possible with `\\`, but doc does not say anything for the  `{`

Comment: I tried this query: ```select * from (select 'some string contains {}' as msg from dual
 union select 'some string without curly braces' as msg from dual) t
where t.msg like '%{%'``` and it also works. Maybe it depends on oracle version